# min & max number of linearly independent vectors required to span $F^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the minimum and maximum number of linearly independent vectors required to span $F^{n}$?

I'm going to guess you need exactly $n$ vectors to span the entire space of $F^{n}$?

No more than $n$, and no less than $n$, but exactly $n$.

True or false?  and Why?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Yes,   exactly $n$. That is a standard theorem in linear algebra. It;s proved in all the books and courses. This website isn't really the place to ask "why".

Comment: apparently every book except "linear algebra demystified" which makes you guess that its a theorem...

Answer (score 0):

If you were to construct a linearly independent set, you'd notice that it cannot contain more elements than $dim(\mathbf{F}^n)=n$. Also, any set S of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbf F^n$ will be a basis for $\mathbf{F}^n$, hence S spans $\mathbf{F}^n$. Adding arbitrarily many more vectors to S does not change the fact that it spans $\mathbf{F}^n$ because these added vectors were **already** in the span of S.

I've found this helpful:  any spanning set can be reduced into a basis, every linearly independent set can be grown into a basis and finally adding elements to a basis set does not change the fact that it spans the whole vector space, but it does make it a linearly dependent set since the added vector is in the span of the original n vectors in the basis.

And the answer to your question is this:  you need $n$ vectors to form a linearly independent set S which spans the whole vector space. Any more vectors added to S, and S is no longer linearly independent, since it already spanned the whole vector space.

Hope that answers your question.